# Create page listing latest user logon and location

Tags: user-accounts, geolocation

Background: Users authenticate to our company SharePoint 2013 site using domain\username, and for those using systems with a trust relationship established with the AD servers, the SharePoint site is in the Local Intranet Zone sites list in IE, and the Intranet zone has been configured to perform "Automatic logon with current user name and password" (non-AD connected PC users manually enter their logon credentials). The logged in user's full name is then displayed in SharePoint, including on every user's "My Site" page.

I have been asked if it is possible to create a webpage on our SharePoint site that automatically updates the most recent logon location (approximation, based on IP address) of a predefined group of traveling users.

Keeping in mind that the users may bookmark sub-site pages -and therefore not always enter the site through the front page- is it possible to automatically generate a page listing:

- the account name
- the latest geolocation
- the time the logon occurred

for the users?

Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list at the root site collection with following fields

1. User
2. IP
3. Logon time
4. Location

Now add following logic in the master page

1. On Page load (document ready) event use following JavaScript to get location details

   ```
   <script>
   <script language="javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript">
   mmjsCountryCode = geoip_country_code();
   mmjsCountryName = geoip_country_name();

   </script>

   For more information http://stackoverflow.com/a/12314951/215207
   ```
2. Now add this information to the list created above. (You need to check if entry exists or not before duplicating list items)
3. Now create a new Page and add list view webpart - You can filter the view to show one records for current user modified date descendin order

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not only missing some key steps about setting up the whole process in SP, most importantly: the Maxmind link above will no longer work as they no longer offer the free service and the link is invalid. Search for a solution integrating Google maps.